# How to change buffer size for lua socket?

Tags: unix, lua, udp, datagram

I have the following lua function that creates, connects, and sends information on a udp socket.

```lua
local udp = ngx.socket.udp
local function write_to_socket(conf, bytes)
  local sock = udp()
  sock:settimeout(conf.timeout)
  sock:setpeername(conf.socket_host, conf.socket_port)
  sock:send(bytes)
  sock:close()
end
```

(I've omitted error handling)

I would like to increase the writing buffer size with an option similar to `so_sndbuf`, but as far as I can tell both [ngx socket](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module?tab=readme-ov-file#ngxsocketudp) and [lua socket](https://w3.impa.br/%7Ediego/software/luasocket/udp) don't offer this ability. Is there a way to change writing buffer size in lua?

I did look into writing C functions to do the socket logic but this is a small part of an application written in lua so I can't change my entry point to run C with `lua_register`.

Answer (score -1):

For [luasocket](https://luarocks.org/modules/lunarmodules/luasocket), since version 3.0.0, you can change the size with `setoption`.

```
local sock = socket.udp()
sock:setoption('send-buffer-size', bytes)
```

By default sending is not buffered, but you can actually achieve buffering by concatenating strings in Lua on your own.

Comment: By default every TCP socket has a socket send buffer.

Comment: @user207421 The question is about UDP and what I was talking about is the buffering behavior of the extension, rather than whether the send buffer exists.